# Find entities containing a string in a list in Spring Data Repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I do have a simple `MongoRepository` and its entities do have a `List<String> tags` attribute. Is there a way to add a `findBy` method to the repository? Something like

```
List<...> findByInTags(@Param("tag") String tag);
```

So all entities containing the given string `tag` in there list `tags` will be returned.

I tried to solve it with a `RestController` and a custom `findByTag` endpoint. But I would like to use HATEOAS for the result format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the spring-data-mongo unit tests: [Person.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Person.java)

```
@Document
public class Person extends Contact {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    ...
    private Set<Address> shippingAddresses;
```

And the [PersonRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/PersonRepository.java)

```
    /**
* Returns the {@link Person} with the given {@link Address} as shipping address.
*
* @param address
* @return
*/
Person findByShippingAddresses(Address address);
```

IIRC, this kind of syntax also works with Collections. So you should be able to use

> List<...> findByTag(String tag);

Comment: Great, I never thought of that. It works also with `List<String>` and not just `Set`.

Comment: Yes, i think  its based on the java.util.Collection interface, so all sub-interfaces should work too.